# Angular.js - ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Angular.js is pretty new to me. I have learned before the $scope method for the controller and now trying the "this" method. For some reason I can not get my ng-repeat to work. here's my code:

HTML:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a ng-click="myCtrl.tab=1" href>one</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="myCtrl.tab=2" href>two</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="myCtrl.tab=3" href>three</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-controller="imageContr as imageCtrl">
        <div ng-show="myCtrl.tab === 1" class="tab">
            <h3>ONE title</h3>
            <p>hello</p>
            <li ng-repeat="item in gallery">
                <img alt="imagealt" ng-src="{{item.photo}}">
            </li>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="myCtrl.tab === 2" class="tab">
            <h3>TWO title</h3>
            <p>how are</p>

        </div>
        <div ng-show="myCtrl.tab === 3" class="tab">
            <h3>THREE title</h3>
            <p>you?</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

APP.JS:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function() {
    this.tab = 1;
});
app.controller('imageContr', function() {
    this.gallery = images;
    var images = {
        photo: 'image1.jpg'
    };
});
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare images before you assign it, and make it an array

```
var images = [{ photo: 'image1.jpg' }];
this.gallery = images;
```

Then in your view:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in imageCtrl.gallery">
    <img alt="imagealt" ng-src="{{item.photo}}">
</li>
```

Comment: thanks, it works :) I also didn't insert the images obj in an array. part of the mistake as well.

Comment: Hi @Tom, if the answer works, feel free to mark it as the solution so that others can skim it more easily when they run into the same problem

Comment: Hey Tyler, thanks. I'm new to stack overflow and not sure how to do that... I've tried to vote for the answer but don't have enough rep.

Comment: You should have a check mark below the voting buttons for each answer -- you can click that to mark an answer as the solution

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the `gallery` on `this` of the controller (which is basically the `$scope`), hence you need to access it in the template via `imageContr` as well:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in imageCtrl.gallery">
   <img alt="imagealt" ng-src="{{item.photo}}">
</li>
```

You could also consider making `gallery` an array, so can easily iterate over it. Or you need to use the ["iterate over object properties"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)-syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

Comment: Using controllerAs syntax, it should be `imageCtrl`, not `imageContr`

Comment: Yep, that's right. I was looking at the controller definition. Thanks.